# C# Serialize PSCredential to XML with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, powershell-cmdlet

Experienced with PowerShell, but new to C#.

I am creating a Binary PowerShell Cmdlet and have run into an issue when trying to serialize PSCredential to XML with the XmlSerializer.

When I serialize the the custom object I have created the PSCredential Properties are empty.

I have the following Custom Object :

```cs
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [XmlRoot(), XmlType("MyNamespace.CustomObject")]
    public class CustomObject
    {
        #region Properties
        [XmlElement]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public string Domain { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public string Database { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Plazas", IsNullable = true)]
        public string[] Plazas { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Filter", IsNullable = true)]
        public string[] Filter { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public PSCredential DatabaseCredential { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public PSCredential LaneCredential { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        // Blank, for Cmdlet and XML Support
        public CustomObject() { }

        public CustomObject(string name, string domain, string Database, PSCredential databaseCredential, PSCredential laneCredentials) 
        { 
        // ...
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The Command I have Written to export the object to XML :

```cs
[Cmdlet(VerbsData.Export, "CustomObject")]
public class ExportCustomObjectCommand : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public CustomObject CustomObject { get; set; }
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    [Alias("Path")]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomObject));

        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(FilePath))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(fs, CustomObject);
        }

    }
}
```

In Powershell :

```
$laneCreds = [pscredential]::new("testuser1", (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String "1234567890"))
$DBCreds = [pscredential]::new("testuser2", (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String "0987654321"))

# Create a new Object
$obj = New-CustomObject -Name "TEST" -Database "1.2.3.4" -Domain "TEST-DOMAIN" -DatabaseCredential $DBCreds -LaneCredential $laneCreds

# verify PSCredentials are there with the original object.
$obj.DatabaseCredential.UserName 
$obj.DatabaseCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

# Output :
testuser2
0987654321

# Exports everything except PSCredentials
Export-CustomObject -CustomObject $obj -Path "C:\temp\test.xml"
```

This is the command that creates a new CustomObject :

```cs
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.New, "CustomObject")
public class NewCustomObjectCommand: Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public string Database {  get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public PSCredential DatabaseCredential { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public PSCredential LaneCredential { get; set; }

    [Parameter()]
    public string[] Plazas { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter()]
    public string[] Filter { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject(Name, Domain, Database, DatabaseCredential, LaneCredential);
        
        if (Filter != null)
        {
            customObject.Filter = Filter;
        }
        
        if (Plazas != null)
        {
            customObject.Plazas = Plazas;
        }

        WriteObject(customObject);
    }
}
```

Test.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyNamespace.CustomObject xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>TEST</Name>
  <Domain>TEST-DOMAIN</Domain>
  <Database>1.2.3.4</Database>
  <Plazas>
    <string>1</string>
    <string>2</string>
    <string>3</string>
  </Plazas>
  <Filter>
    <string>4.3.2.1</string>
    <string>5.6.7.8</string>
  </Filter>
  <DatabaseCredential />
  <LaneCredential />
</MyNamespace.CustomObject>
```

I can use the PSCredentials when the object is in memory, however when writing to file the PSCredentials are null.

I was expecting the PSCredentials to be present in the appropriate fields.

I suspect it has something to do with how secure strings need to be handled.

Is this something that can be done in this manner?

Comment: Where are you writing the properties to the instance of the class CustomObject?  You are missing $obj.LaneCredential = $laneCreds and $obj.DatabaseCredential = $DBCreds

Comment: @jdweng I wrote a command to create a new instance of CustomObject, I have added the code to the question. $DBcreds and $laneCreds are passed as parameters to the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue, you need to use the `PSSerializer` from the `System.management.Automation` assembly rather than `XmlSerializer` and write the resulting string to file.

The following code produces the desired output:

```cs
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsData.Export, "CustomObject")]
    public class ExportCustomObjectCommand : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public CustomObject CustomObject { get; set; }
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            string serialized = PSSerializer.Serialize(CustomObject);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FilePath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(serialized);
            }
        }
    }
}
```